# jQuery replace text of element on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, replace

With jQuery, I'm trying to replace the text, including the span, inside these links on hover. Then when the user hover's off, the original text is displayed again.

```
<a class="btn" href="#">
    <img src="#" alt=""/>
    <span>Replace me</span> please
</a>

<a class="btn" href="#">
    <img src="#" alt=""/>
    <span>Replace me</span> please
</a>
```

The final output should be

```
<a class="btn" href="#">
    <img src="#" alt=""/>
    I'm replaced!
</a>
```

I'm toying around with but not sure how to replace it back. Any ideas?

```
$('.btn').hover(function(){
    $(this).text("I'm replaced!");
});
```

Comment: This would be much easier if *all* the content to be replaced was inside some element.

Comment: Do you need it to be done with jQuery or is it static text?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/#example-0 should show you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$('.btn').hover(
    function() {
        var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)
        $this.data('defaultText', $this.text());
        $this.text("I'm replaced!");
    },
    function() {
        var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)
        $this.text($this.data('defaultText'));
    }
);
```

you could save the original text in a `data-defaultText` attribute stored in the node itself so to avoid variables

Comment: you posted this 43 seconds before me, but the funny thing is, my internet went down for a split second when I clicked send and I had to input a captcha when I sent it

Comment: Personally, this replace it, but then when the mouse goes out, it still keeps the new text!

Comment: Note that the key in the html node must be kebab-cased, in this example: `<div class="btn" data-default-text="foobar">`

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick

```
$(function(){
  var prev;    

  $('.btn').hover(function(){
  prev = $(this).text();
      $(this).text("I'm replaced!");
  }, function(){
      $(this).text(prev)
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn').hover(function() {
    // store $(this).text() in a variable     
    $(this).text("I'm replaced!");
},
function() {
    // assign it back here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add another function to the hover event like this:

```
$('.btn').hover(function(){
    $(this).text("I'm replaced!");
}, function() {
    $(this).text("Replace me please");
});
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3JDZs/) for demo

Comment: wow now i realize how slow i am... and a jsfiddle link was a bad idea here :'(

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to store it in a variable in order to set it back to what it was, try:

```
var text;

$(".btn").hover(function () {
    text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("I'm replaced!");
},
function () {
    $(this).text(text);
});
```