# Change label text on mouse over with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to change the value of a label on mouse over. This is what I have done so far:

```
$(function () {
    var hoverOff = "";
    $("[id*=GV] td").hover(function () {
        hoverOff = $("label", $(this).closest("td")).text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyMethode.aspx/GetNewValue?text=" + hoverOff,
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("label", $(this).closest("td")).html(data.d);
                }
            });
        },
        function () {
            $("label", $(this).closest("td")).html(hoverOff);
        }
);});
```

At the beginning I save the current text in hoverOff and send that value to the method GetNewValue wich returns the new value and inside ajax success I want to apply that value to the label. The problem is that the text for label never changes, although data.d contains the new text. Should I use something else instead of .html()?

Comment: How do you debug it? Is error fired? Looks like the contentype doesn't match data passed to server

Comment: I can debug With Visual Studio (I also start the Project in Internet Explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside ajax callback isn't referring to the current hovered TD but to the jqXHR object. You can use `$.ajax` context option:

`context: this,`

BTW, `$(this).closest("td")` is quite unrelevant because obviously, even you have nested TDs, `$(this).closest("td")` will always return the current TD, so you could just use `this`:

```
hoverOff = $("label", this).text();
```

And `data: "{}",` could be `data: {},`, no point of setting a string here. >> because you are setting contentype to JSON

Comment: Thanks for your tips. My code looks much better now

Answer (score 1):

It's a context problem you can't use `this` inside success function, try this code:

```
$(function () {
    var hoverOff = "";
    $("[id*=GV] td").hover(function () {
        var label = $("label", $(this).closest("td"));
        hoverOff = label.text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyMethode.aspx/GetNewValue?text=" + hoverOff,
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                label.html(data.d);
                }
            });
        },
        function () {
            label.html(hoverOff);
        }
);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10701170/3421811

```
$('.btn').hover(
function() {
    var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)
    $this.data('initialText', $this.text());
    $this.text("I'm replaced!");
},
function() {
    var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)
    $this.text($this.data('initialText'));
}
);
```