# Changing text onhover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with the text 'one' inside of it. When you hover over it, I want to change the text to 'two', and when you stop hovering over it, I want to change the text back to 'one'. I tried to do this using jQuery, but after it change into 'two', it doesn't change back to 'one' once you stop hovering over it. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hover(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith("two");
        }, function(){
        $(this).replaceWith("one");
    });
});
</script>

<p>one</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery replace text of element on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701124/jquery-replace-text-of-element-on-hover)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `text()`, since `replaceWith()` will replace the whole element, and you are replacing it with a text and not an element so the selection of the element is being lost the next time.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hover(function(){
        $(this).text("two");
        }, function(){
        $(this).text("one");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>one</p>
```

Comment: How come this doesn't work? $(this).text("two").fadeIn(3000);

Comment: because it is already visible ! maybe fadeOut() ? or try `$(this).text("two").hide().fadeIn(777);`

Comment: @Anonymous0day Ha! So, hide it, and then make it fadeIn! Smart!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hover(function(){
        $(this).html("two");
        }, function(){
        $(this).html("one");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>one</p>
```